# Load from SQLite "kind of" slow when setAdapter()

Tags: android, android-asynctask, fragment, android-adapter

I'm loading a `Fragment` which has a `ListView` that I fill with a `CustomAdapter` that gets some data from my db. I'm loading it with an `AsyncTask` but I'm not setting the Adapter (`setAdapter()`) until the job is done, so when I get into this `Fragment` there's a little bit of time of waiting (since the button click until the `Fragment` is loaded) and the transition is not 100% smooth.

I tried to load the `View` of the `Fragment` first while the db is being read, and setting the Adapter afterwards. What happens in this case is that my `LinearLayout android:id="@+id/android:empty"` is shown until the Adapter is set and it's not very nice. (OK, it's just some milliseconds, but still).

The approach I want to handle this problem is to show a "loading circle" instead of the `android:empty LinearLayout` AND when the user clicks the back button, this circle shouldn't be shown again (the LinearLayout DOES appear again before the closing fragment transition...).

Comment: You could use a `Loader`.

Comment: I didn't know them, I'll take a look. Thanks.

Comment: Good luck. They're not trivial, but so worth it. Plenty of tutorials, too.